# How to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I am trying to find the following limit.

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}dx$

I have tried methods like Taylor Expansion and Reduction formula to solve the inner integral but that is not working. I also tried L'Hospital Rule. I just multiplied and divided by $\sqrt \frac1n$ and because both the numerator and denominator are of the form 0 I thought it will be alright to apply the rule. Am I wrong in doing that? Also it didn't work out as after taking derivative the term still seems to be of the form $\frac00$.

I am also not sure as the question asks for a range for the limit and the answer given is $\frac12 < L < 2$. How can I approach this problem?